# How to get absolute path to files from FileDialog in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, filedialog

I am using SWT's FileDialog to let user select several files:

```
FileDialog dlg = new FileDialog(s, SWT.MULTI);
dlg.setFilterPath(somePath);
String fn = dlg.open();
if (fn != null)
  String [] files = dlg.getFileNames()
```

While `fn` returns the absolute path to the directory, the `files` array contains relative paths. I would like to get an absolute path for each file. Is there a way of doing this in Java that works across platforms (Win, Linux, MacOS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to append the filename to the given filter path.  To avoid worrying about path separators and the like, you can just use the `File` class.  For example:

```
String[] filenames = dialog.getFileNames();
String filterPath = dialog.getFilterPath();

File[] selectedFiles = new File[filenames.length];

for(int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++)
{
    if(filterPath != null && filterPath.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        selectedFiles[i] = new File(filterPath, filenames[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedFiles[i] = new File(filenames[i]);
    }
}
```

If you need the path as a `String`, you can of course use the `getAbsolutePath()` method on the resultant `File`s.

Comment: What if the user changes directory other than what we have set in FilterPath?

Comment: Having just tried it, the filter path changes when the user changes directory.